# Use password with Git::Repository

Tags: git, perl, authentication

Is there a way to use a password with `Git::Repository`? I've tried adding the password to the arguments in the `run()`-Function (`$repository->run('pull', $git_pw);`), which <del>seems to work, but</del> doesn't work and gives me a warning like

```
fatal: '[PASSWORD]' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly at ./list_commits.pl line 33
```

I can't seem to find anything useful in the [Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~book/Git-Repository-1.308/lib/Git/Repository.pm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're entering the realm of emulating user interaction, which I always shy away from. :-)
The nice thing about git, after all, is that it is also supposed to talk to programs.

Anyway, to solve your problem, I would try to do this:

```
$repository->run( 'pull', { input => "$git_pw\n" } );
```

But it's very likely to fail, for example because the password would be sent too early.
I'm interested in the results of your attempts, if only to update the documentation.
(I'm the author of Git::Repository.)

A completely different solution would involve a public key and `ssh-agent`, and would remove the need to type a password.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's probably sending the input too early, which results in nothing but the password-promt to happen :-/ Could you elaborate the `public-key/ssh-agent`-solution a bit more? :)

Comment: Assuming a remote url like `ssh://user@host:1234/srv/git/example`,
you could setup the `user` account at the remote `host` to accept public key authentication (using the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file).


If that's acceptable to you, the simplest thing is to have a public key (with `ssh-keygen`) with an empty passphrase (so that it can be automatically be used by batch scripts).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `ssh` program git uses setting `GIT_SSH` to one that doesn't ask for the password.

Using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) is easy to connect to the remote host through SSH and then use a script to run `git` remote commands over that connection.

I have included a sample script on `Net::OpenSSH` distribution that shows how to do it with raw `git`. Adapting it to be used with `Git::Repository` should be quite easy.

The sample program is [here](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH/blob/master/sample/git_with_password.pl), and the slave ssh program is [here](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH/blob/master/sample/git_ssh_through_mux.pl) (it needs to be reachable from `$PATH`).

**Update**: in any case, note that you should probably use public-key authentication if you can, instead of password authentication.

Comment: I'll use publickey-authentication